# How to remove hyphen in span? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have breadcrumbs that generate a hyphen inside a specific link.

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
   <span class="home">
        <a href="#"><span property="name">Home</span></a>
   </span>

   <span>
        <a href="#" class="post post-vehicle-archive"><span property="name">books-for-sale</span></a>
   </span>

   <span>
        <a href="#" class="book-name"><span property="name">Soup for the sould</span></a>
   </span>
</div>
```

I want to remove the hypens inside class="post post-vehicle-archive".

This is the code that I tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(function() {
        var getTermName = j('.breadcrumbs .post.post-type-archeive > span');
        j(getTermName ).text(value.replace(/\-/g, " "));

    });
</script>
```

The result should be "Books For Sale"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Nothing at all or an error?

Comment: You have the wrong selector for getTermName and `value` is undefined (replace it with (`j(getTermName).text()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to make use of the receiver function of `.text()`

```
var getTermName = j('.breadcrumbs .post.post-type-archeive > span');
getTermName.text(function(i,value) {
  return value.replace(/\-/g, " ")
});
```

If you want to change your text to title case then use the below code,

```
var getTermName = j('.breadcrumbs .post.post-type-archeive > span');
getTermName.text(function(i,value) {
  return value.replace(/\-/g, " ").split(" ").map(function(function(val){
     return val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
  }).join(" ");
});
```

Or don't make the things much complex,

JS:

```
var getTermName = j('.breadcrumbs .post.post-type-archeive > span').addClass("titleCase");
getTermName.text(function (i, value) {
    return value.replace(/\-/g, " ")
});
```

CSS:

```
.titleCase {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) callback to update the innerText of all the elements.

1. Iterate over all the breadcrumbs
2. Remove the hyphens, and make the first character of each of the word uppercase

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(function() {
  // This will loop over all the matched `<a>` elements
  // Corrected selector
  j('.breadcrumbs span a').text(function(i, oldText) {

    //     To capitalize the first character of first word
    return oldText[0].toUpperCase() + oldText.substring(1).replace(/-[a-z]/g, function(m) {

      // Add space and capitalize the first character
      return ' ' + m[1].toUpperCase();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <span class="home">
    <a href="#"><span property="name">Home</span>
  </a>
  </span>

  <span>
    <a href="#" class="post post-vehicle-archive"><span property="name">books-for-sale</span>
  </a>
  </span>

  <span>
    <a href="#" class="book-name"><span property="name">Soup for the sould</span>
  </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Regex Explanation:**

1. `-`: Matches hyphen literally. No need to escape when using outside of Character Class
2. `[a-z]`: Matches a single lowercase alphabet
3. `g`: The global flag, to match all possible matches.

**Note:** If you want to capitalize the breadcrumbs of the space-separated too then use following regex

```
/[-\s][a-z]/g
```

Comment: Nice answer @Tushar. Thank you